Pandas group by filter results
I am using pandas and getting data and using group by.  However I am not sure how to filter out unwanted data from getting returned. I only want the count for 1's and not 0's.
print(df.groupby(item)['event'].apply(lambda x: (x==1).sum()).reset_index(name='count'))
hpb   count
0     55
1     36

I've also used the following and it's returning the same info for all columns.
print(patients.query("event==1 and hbp==1").groupby('hbp').count())

       age    cp    eject  ......
hbp
 1      36     36    36

My desired output is below.
hpb   count
1     36

Here is my data I am reading into the dataframe patients.  I am trying to get the hbp data where event is 1 and hbp is 1 using query or group by.
Currently I am getting both 1 and 0 counts but I only display the hbp 1 counts.  see desired output above.
hbp event ..etc
1       1
0       1
1       1
1       1
0       1


Your solution is possible change with specify column after groupby and use sum or count or size, because processing 1 values:
print(patients.query("event==1 and hbp==1")
              .groupby('hbp')['event']
              .sum()
              .reset_index(name='count'))

Or first filter and then count hbp values by Series.value_counts:
print (patients.query("event==1 and hbp==1")['hbp']
               .value_counts()
               .reset_index(name='count'))

   hbp  count
0    1     36


All of the code is giving me the same output.  I am still getting both 0 56 and 1 36 output.  I am looking for away to only return the output for 1   36. I updated my question with what I am trying to achieve.

@newdeveloper - So need patients["event"].eq(1).sum() ?

So there is no way to get only the counts for hbp 1

@newdeveloper - Sure, it is possible, solution is changed
